# In Photoshop, what does the * to the right of the colour mode mean?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In the title bar of an image, what does the * to the right of the image mode mean?

[image]

At first I thought it meant there were unsaved changes, but it turns out I get a second * in that scenario:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * means there's a colour profile mismatch.

[This article](http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/photoshop-color-management-warnings.html), while quite old, explains colour profiles and how you can remove the * by resolving the mismatched colour profile.